# Detect numbers surrounded by equal numbers in a matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I need an algorithm that extracts from a matrix those fields that are surrounded by equal values. I'll provide you an example to see it clearer.

- This is my intitial matrix.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

- As you can see, the spaces marked with an "X" are those fields that
  are surrounded by equal values, in this case, surrounded by value 1.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 \\
        1 &   & 1 &   &   &   & 1 \\
        1 &   & 1 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 \\
          &   & 1 & X & 1 &   & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & X & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
          &   & 1 & X & X & X & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

The question is if there exists any mathematic formula that can return which are those fields. If not, I'd be grateful if you gave me some theorems that can help me developing the algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the entries of your matrix always 0 or 1?

Comment: Actually, not one space marked with an "X" in your example is *surrounded* by $1$. Do you mean a "connected" subset of entries surrounded by the same value?

Comment: there are some 1's surrounded by zeros which are not marked by an X. Such as element$(4,3)$.

Comment: surrounded meaning what, in all four directions? or only horizontal? or all eight?

Comment: Yes, entries will always be 1 and 0. And by surrounded I mean that if number 1 was a wall, you wouldn't be able to get out of that room, as you can see in the example. Is it clearer now? Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Given the shape of your matrix, the easiest thing I can think of is: for every border $0$ cell, exclude the neighbouring $0$ cells. The remaining ones will be those enclosed by $1$.

Comment: As this functionality is used in many paint programs (usually called "fill brush" or so), I think finding an algorithm is not hard by searching in google, or open source paint program. (by the way they may use a internal OpenGL/directX/.. function and so be less helpful)

Comment: @A.P. And then iterate it for the next neighborhoods. I realized this idea in my answer.

Comment: @CutieKrait It seems that in Delphi (and Pascal) such the painting procedure (called FloodFill), is based on the algorithm, which is somewhat similar to mine. “Use FloodFill to fill a possibly non-rectangular region of the image with the value of Brush. The boundaries of the region to be filled are determined by moving outward from the point (X,Y) until a color boundary involving the Color parameter is encountered”. (from Delphi help)

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, sorry, I didn't really follow your Pascal code. A short description of your algorithm would have helped. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid that no theorems or formulas can help you much in the developing of the algorithm, and therefore  you should concentrate on the algorithm itself. I wrote a simple Pascal program to illustrate one of the simplest of such algorithms.

```
program SurNum;
const
  m=7;
  n=7;
  var
    IFi,OFi:Text;
    tC:Char;
    i,j,k:Byte;
    a:array[1..m,1..n]of Byte;
    Found:Boolean;
begin

{matrix input}
assign(IFi,'input.txt');
reset(IFi);
for i:=1 to m do begin
  for j:=1 to n do begin
    read(IFi,tC);
    if tC='1' then a[i,j]:=1 else a[i,j]:=0;
  end;
  readln(IFi);
end;
close(IFi);

{main part}

{find initial unisolated cells}
for j:=1 to n do if a[1,j]=0 then a[1,j]:=2;
for j:=1 to n do if a[m,j]=0 then a[m,j]:=2;
for i:=1 to m do if a[i,1]=0 then a[i,1]:=2;
for i:=1 to m do if a[i,n]=0 then a[i,n]:=2;

{try to find additional unisolated cells}

repeat
Found:=False;
for i:=2 to m-1 do for j:=2 to n-1 do
  if (a[i,j]=0) and ((a[i-1,j]=2) or (a[i+1,j]=2) or (a[i,j-1]=2) or (a[i,j+1]=2)) 
   then begin a[i,j]:=2; Found:=True end;
until not Found;

{matrix output}

assign(OFi,'output.txt');
rewrite(OFi);
for i:=1 to m do begin
  for j:=1 to n do begin
    if a[i,j]=0 then write(OFi,'X');
    if a[i,j]=1 then write(OFi,'1');
    if a[i,j]=2 then write(OFi,' ');
  end;
  writeln(OFi);
end;
close(OFi);

end.
```

The contents of the file “input.txt” is:

```
1111101
1010001
1011101
0010101
1110111
0010001
1111111
```

The contents of the file “output.txt” should be:

```
11111 1
1 1   1
1 111 1
  1X1 1
111X111
  1XXX1
1111111
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! It's been really useful.

Comment: There's a theorem in digital topology called digital Jordan curve theorem. the proof of this theorem may be helpful for writing a program. (Or maybe your algorithm may prove that theorem! by the way I can read a C++ program more easily)

Comment: I suspect that the proof of this theorem is inductive. * The problem of finding the curves in the matrix seems to be similar to the initial problem. And I tried to simplify the realization of the algorithm, and I based it on a matrix order of cells, not on the topology.  *  I don’t expect that my algorithm can prove the theorem, because it simply fills an (outer)  area and cannot apriori show the boundness of the inner area. *  I don’t write in C.